# Funds that approximate savings accounts

Tags: united-states, etf, savings, mutual-funds

I have money in IRAs that I shouldn't take out to put into a savings account.  I'd like to get a relatively safe 1.5-2% return on these, similar to what I might expect from a savings account in terms of security and return.

Are there well-established funds that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Sounds like you want a money market fund. However, money market funds have no guarantee of capital preservation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options.

- Many banks and credit unions offer CDs that can be used in an IRA. The credit union I belong to has 1/2/3 year CDs that have the same rate as a regular CD. They also have a "savings account" that can be used in an IRA.
- Many brokerages have funds that try to do exactly what you want. They have CD's, they have money market accounts, you can even invest in Treasuries.